# How to use enumerate function in for loop starting from a specific value?

Tags: python, for-loop, data-science, enumerate

I want this code to cycle through the entire dataset and to be performed each time 'CAFE' is in a line. Currently, it only occurs for the first appearance of CAFE. In other words, I want to specify the start of the enumerate function as the line with CAFE in it, but I am unable to put an argument of start = 'CAFE' inside the enumerate function because the string 'CAFE' cannot be interpreted as an integer.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as dataset:
    for line in dataset:
        if 'CAFE' in line:
            for i, lt in enumerate(dataset):
                if i > 1 and i < 130 and i %2 == 0:
                   lt_1 = int(lt, 16)
                   lt_2 = float(str(lt_1))
                   print(lt_2)
             else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: `enumerate(dataset)` consumes the remainder of the lines in the file, so the outer `for line in dataset` loop stops iterating.

Comment: can you provide example text (simplified, like 10 lines or fewer) and expected output?

Comment: Hi -- one quick thing, you don't need the `else: pass` lines. Another thought, enumerate twice? `for outer_line_number, line in enumerate(dataset):` ...?

Comment: John Gordon thank you. Is there a way to change my code so that the for line in dataset loop continues to iterate?

Comment: mrblewog thank you. where would I put that second enumeration code?

Answer (score 0):

Well `enumerate(iterable[,start=integer])` takes inetger as start not string and It will be helpful if you provide data.txt

enumerate is equivalent to:

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)